# MySQL How can I optismise this query so it doesn't bring my MySQL server to its knees

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dedicated server with SSD's and a very decent CPU and 32GB RAM.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), id, DATE1, DATE2 FROM TABLE 
WHERE SOMETHING1 LIKE '%' AND 
`SOMETHING2` LIKE '%' AND 
`SOMETHING3` LIKE '%' AND 
`SOMETHING4` LIKE '%' AND 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calendar_table WHERE dt > DATE2 AND dt <= DATE1 AND isWeekday = 1 AND isHoliday = 0 ) < '3' AND 
(DATE3 BETWEEN '' AND '' AND DATE3 != 'NULL' AND DATE3 != '0000-00-00') AND
`SOMETHING5` LIKE 'this'
```

This query takes place on a main table that has just over 2'000 rows and 108 columns.

Is there a more optimal way to do this query, currently it takes about 4.8974 seconds (this is a dynamic page with a form to change the search criteria)

Any pointers would be highly appreciated as it is beginning to get on my nerves!

Thanks for reading guys

Comment: you can start with replacing `SELECT COUNT(*)` with `SELECT COUNT(ANY_FIELD_NAME)` for example `SELECT COUNT(ID)

Comment: Why you add `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calendar_table WHERE dt > DATE2 AND dt <= DATE1 AND isWeekday = 1 AND isHoliday = 0 ) < '3' AND 
(DATE3 BETWEEN '' AND '' AND DATE3 != 'NULL' AND DATE3 != '0000-00-00')` this query in where condition ?

Comment: You should try and exclude any parts of the criteria where they are not entered - so `SOMETHING1 LIKE '%'` should not be put in if there are no criteria for it.  Same with DATE3 - not having this stuff in the where clause makes it much easier to read and optimise.

Comment: 2000 rows is nothing, I bet you can get all of them even faster in memory. Maybe some filters can easily be done in memory? How big is the calendar_table? Is it indexed? Why is there a count in the select while there is no GROUPING, so this is always 1?

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for your input, I have found what i've done to be incorrect as you guys pointed out. although the issue seems to still reside, I will edit my original Q with updated info on what I have done to alleviate some performance issues from some of the queries and include examples of other queries (from the same set that are messed up)